# Trying to create an array of node pointers using dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm currently trying to do something simple, turn my list of nodes into an array of pointers to the nodes, so that I could use it for another functionality.

```
typedef struct {
  int data;
} myNode;
```

In the function where I'm trying to make my array of node pointers, I write something like (assume I have a list called myList of all the nodes):

```
myNode** aryPtr = malloc(sizeof(myNode*)) * numItemsInList);
```

and for each spot, I allocate memory for the pointer doing:

```
int inc = 0;
int z = 0;
aryPtr[inc] = malloc(sizeof(myNode));
aryPtr[inc] = &(myList[z]);
inc += 1;
z += 1;
```

I've been trying to do something like this to go about storing the pointers to each of my nodes in an array, but haven't had success and don't entirely understand how to make an array of pointers (using a double pointer). Any help on how to store pointers into a dynamically allocated array of pointers would help a lot.

Comment: `myNode** aryPtr = malloc(sizeof(myNode*)) * numItemsInList);` is multiplying the pointer returned by `malloc` by `numItemsInList` -- not what you want. `myNode **aryPtr = malloc (sizeof *aryPtr * numItemsInList);` which will allocate `numItemsInList` pointers which you can then allocate a node and assign the address to each.

Comment: Please post the actual code, not something your wrote down just now for SO only.

Answer (score 4):

These two lines are a little problematic:

```
aryPtr[inc] = malloc(sizeof(myNode));
aryPtr[inc] = &(myList[z]);
```

The first assignment

```
aryPtr[inc] = malloc(sizeof(myNode));
```

allocates memory, and makes `aryPtr[inc]` point to that memory. But the next assignment

```
aryPtr[inc] = &(myList[z]);
```

throws away the result of the `malloc` call, and reassigns `aryPtr[inc]` to point somewhere else. That leads to a memory leak.

It's similar to having a simple int variable, and assigning it multiple times:

```
int a;
a = 5;
a = 10;
```

And then wonder why `a` is not equal to `5`.

To solve this problem, either drop the first assignment with the `malloc` and only have

```
aryPtr[inc] = &myList[z];  // Make aryPtr[inc] point to myList[z]
```

Or dereference the destination pointer to copy the structure:

```
aryPtr[inc] = malloc(sizeof(myNode));
*aryPtr[inc] = myList[z];  // Copy the structure itself
```

---

Another couple of things:

With the code you show (you really need to provide a proper [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) it looks like you're always using index `0` for both `aryPtr` and `myList`. You also use the same index for both `aryPtr` and `myList`, so you only need a single variable for that.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks, also I want an array of pointers, wouldn't dereferencing it get me the actual values and not an actual reference to the pointer? How would I go about doing this

Comment: @FlyinProgrammer Considering your use of `&(myList[z])` that indicates that `myList[z]` is an instance of the structure. By using `*aryPtr[inc] = myList[z]` you will then copy the structure. It's similar to `myNode myStructure; myStructure = myList[z];`. Of course, this requires you to *keep* the `malloc` call.